# Specify current time for New York time zone in SQL? (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

For some reason, the VPN on my account identifies me as being in Australia or London. When I try to change my precise location in my Google setting it gives me errors saying I am either not authorized to do that or it cannot identify my location despite my location turned on.

I am currently doing the following to get the current time. Hoping to specify a timezone

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
select datetime(current_timestamp, 'America/New_York')
```

By definition, a `timestamp` in BQ is UTC, so there is no such thing as a timestamp in local time.  But it is easy enough to get the `datetime` as the local time.